# Are there equivalents to Python's eval() and exec() in Java?

Tags: java, python

Disclaimer: I **know** that Python's [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#eval) represents the possibility of a security breach and that [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec) is rarely used. But I really need them in my project.

Are there equivalents to them in Java? Is it possible to evaluate expressions and execute Java code from String objects?

EDIT: This question is different from the one proposed because I also want an exec() (Which means that I want to execute general Java code from Strings objects, not just mere expressions).

Comment: Java isn't a scripting language, but there are scripting languages that run on the JVM. Inlcuding jython (which is python in Java). Also, there is `ScriptEngine` (which include JavaScript).

Comment: *"This question is different from the one proposed because I also want an exec() (Which means that I want to execute general Java code from Strings objects, not just mere expressions)"* - Then the answer is no